# node.js request fails for umts Stick Webserver (huawei)

Tags: node.js, rest, request

i´m trying to get websites / xml objects from the huawei umts stick internal web gui.

I´ve written a wrapper in c using libcurl which works fine. Now i want to port this to node using request.

When i call a url with curl from console like this:

```
curl -G "http://192.168.1.1/api/monitoring/status"
```

I get normal result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<ConnectionStatus>901</ConnectionStatus>
<SignalStrength>99</SignalStrength>
<SignalIcon>5</SignalIcon>
<CurrentNetworkType>4</CurrentNetworkType>
<CurrentServiceDomain>3</CurrentServiceDomain>
<RoamingStatus>0</RoamingStatus>
<BatteryStatus></BatteryStatus>
<BatteryLevel></BatteryLevel>
<simlockStatus></simlockStatus>
</response>
```

When i try to call this site with request:

```
var request = require("request");

var options = {
   url: "http://192.168.1.1/api/monitoring/status"

};

request.get(options, function(error, response, body) {

if(error)
{
    console.log(error);
}
console.log("statusCode: " + response.statusCode);
console.log("statusText: " + response.statusText);
console.log(body);



});
```

I got an 400 Error:

```
statusCode: 400
statusText: undefined
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>IPWEBS - 400 Bad Request</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY><H2>400 Bad Request</H2>
<P>The request generated an error response.</P>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Any idea on this subject?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that `curl` is sending a header that the server requires. Try changing your options to:

```
var options = {
  url: "http://192.168.1.1/api/monitoring/status",
  headers: {
    'User-Agent': 'curl/7.30.0',
    'Accept': '*/*'
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your hint, it tried it but unfortunately the result is the same :( StatusCode 400

Comment: Just for good measure, maybe add `jar: false` to your options? Shouldn't matter as that is the default and you're not going lots of places, but just to rule it out.